# Visual Studio -- On Windows Server 2008 R2 vs. Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm working on an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2010 remotely (over lan) on a very powerful windows server machine. I work for a small non-profit and the previous developer wrote and developed on this machine, so I came in and have been constricted to this setup.  Visual Studio seems to run a bit slowly/choppy on this OS.  I'm wondering if this is normal and if it is a better practice to develop locally on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Yes, the previous "developer" developed right on the production server, had no source control, had no staging machine.  It's a bit of a mess

Comment: This setup could be related to licensing. Maybe they only have 1 license and wanted to share it between developers? I guess you remote into the server using Remote Desktop or some other tool? If it is the case, then it will be very unpleasant to work this way :( If you can, install VS express locally and work in it, then deploy to the server.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently remoting in via remote desktop, and yes it does seem to be an unpleasant, cumbersome method. I figured it may have to do with licensing, I've inquired about it.

Answer (score 0):

Most developers I know run Visual Studio on their local machine. Everyone's case is different, so there's really no way for us to answer this question without actually being there. So do it, and see what works better for you. No one on SO can answer this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran Server 2008 as a desktop OS on my previous machine for about 3 years - 4GB RAM, AMD CPU, had no problems developing with it so I don't think it's the OS per se, unless it's been installed or configured badly.

But no, that's not a normal scenario, it's never a good idea to do all the development on the production machine.

The slowness/choppiness could be a number of things: -

- if the machine is being used to host the application you're developing, is the application actually in use *while you're developing* ? If the server is periodically or regularly under load, this could account for slowness
- if the above is true, please tell me the actual ASP.NET website is a copy of the development codebase, and you're not just compiling the site in-place.. as it's being used.. the horror
- is the machine doing anything else ? Is SQL Server also running on that machine, is it sending emails, are there some app-related windows services ?
- have you tried profiling the application, or at least using PerfMon to see what's going on ?
- any driver issues ? have you checked the eventlogs ?
- how fast is your internet connection ?

In short it could be a number of things, but the development experience on Server 2008 should be no different from Vista, Win7 or 8.